# How to do parallel operation with if condition in Neon intrinsics?

Tags: arm, simd, neon, intrinsics

I have asked a question for vclt_s8 comparation.
[Does anybody know how to use Neon intrinsics uint8x8_t vclt_s8 (int8x8_t, int8x8_t)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389970/does-anybody-konw-how-to-use-neon-intrinsics-uint8x8-t-vclt-s8-int8x8-t-int8x8)

However, if we have such code:

```
if(a > b + c) {
    a = b + c;
} else if(a < b - c) {
    a = b - c;
}
```

How can I transform it to Neon intrinsics? It seems that we can not do 8 operator parallel operation in such case. Isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously you can't do branching with SIMD, so you have to look at how do implement this kind of logic in a branchless way, using masks. I'll just give pseudo code, so you get the general idea - coding this should be fairly straightforward:

```
bc = b + c       ; get `(b + c)` in a vector register
mask = a > bc    ; use compare instruction to generate mask (-1 = true, 0 = false)
bc = bc & mask   ; use bitwise AND to zero out elements of `(b + c)` which we do not want
a = a & ~mask    ; use bitwise ANDC to zero out elements of `a` which we do not want
a = a | bc       ; combine required elements into `a` using bitwise OR

bc = b - c       ; get `(b - c)` in a vector register
mask = a < bc    ; use compare instruction to generate mask (-1 = true, 0 = false)
bc = bc & mask   ; use bitwise AND to zero out elements of `(b - c)` which we do not want
a = a & ~mask    ; use bitwise ANDC to zero out elements of `a` which we do not want
a = a | bc       ; combine required elements into `a` using bitwise OR
```

Note that I've cheated a little here and omitted the `else` from your scalar code (assuming that the two branches are mutually exclusive) so what I've implemented is actually equivalent to:

```
if (a > b + c) {
    a = b + c;
}
if (a < b - c) {
    a = b - c;
}
```

If this is a bad assumption then you'll need to do some additional bitwise operations to implement the logical `else`.

Comment: Let a = 2, b = 2, c = -1... You'll need to handle that else properly! (OP is using 's8' intrinsics so I guess signed is important to them)

Comment: @James: not necessarily - it depends on the use case - from the context of image/signal processing my guess is that `c` is always positive - if that's not the case however it's easy enough to add a few more bitwise instructions to implement the `else`, as I said above, but you don't want to do this and sacrifice performance if it's not needed.

Comment: mask is signed or unsigned? 
int8x8_t mask; or
uint8x8_t mask;

Comment: @BonderWu: it really doesn't matter - each element is all 1s for "true" (think of this as 255 or -1, whichever you prefer) and all 0s for "false". See the accepted answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389970/does-anybody-know-how-to-use-neon-intrinsics-uint8x8-t-vclt-s8-int8x8-t-int8x8) where they use an unsigned mask result.

Comment: @BonderWu: Accept the answer if this helped you solve the problem

Comment: @Anoop K. Prabhu , OK, thanks. I take sick leave yesterday, sorry.